# Checking if an arralist contains an excel's cell value

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList<Cell> RM = new ArrayList<Cell>() ;`

where `RM=[aaa,bbb]` and where `aaa` and `bbb` are some cells from an excel file
I use this code to get the cells values into the arraylist.

```
   Row row = sheet.getRow(1);
    Iterator<Cell> cells1 = row.cellIterator();

while( cells1.hasNext() ) {
    Cell cell = cells1.next();  

    if (Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING==cell.getCellType()) {
        RM.add(cell);
    }
}
```

Then I am trying to see if the arraylist contains aaa or bbb, but it doesnt recognise the command. System.out.println(RM) shows the proper results [aaa,bbb] but if add an if(contains) condition it wont:

```
if (RM.contains("aaa")) {

System.out.println("ok"); }
```

Comment: Your list contains `Cell` type, and you are checking for `String`. Of course that will not get you `true`. Try testing for some `Cell` type with `"aaa"` value in it.

Comment: This could have been prevented if you had used generics on your arraylist too, which you should have: `ArrayList RM = new ArrayList<Cell>();` now if you try to run your code, you'll get an error because you're using the wrong object types for the comparison

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans. No, `contains()` would give compiler error. The `contains` method takes an `Object` as parameter.

Comment: Is there a different expression than contains for Cell type? Or should I try to convert cell to string? @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: I am confused. How could I test if a cell type contains a specific value? @RohitJain

Comment: Either do a contains() check with Cell objects, or use an `ArrayList<String>()` and insert `cell.getText()` (or whatever its API is for retrieving the cell text, of course). If your intention is to store cell text, the latter is by far the better choice. @Rohit Jain: good point, forgot that didn't get a generics override

Comment: Use a `Cell` type object in the `contains()` method. Override `equals()` in `Cell` to check for equality based on some value. For further help, you need to show how your `Cell` type looks like.

Comment: my cell type is just some literals. aaa in an excel cell @RohitJain

Comment: updated my arraylist: ArrayList<Cell> RM = new ArrayList<Cell>() ;

Answer (score 0):

Changed it to:

```
ArrayList<String> RM = new ArrayList<String>() ;
RM.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
```

and contains() works properly